# WS-Security C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, soap

I have this C# code that generates a binary base 64 username token to connect to a wsdl.

```
var client = new StandardApiClient();
var credentials = client.ClientCredentials.UserName;
credentials.UserName = "myusername";
credentials.Password = "mypassword";
```

This creates the following xml

```
 <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-29" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>myusername</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">bLW62fQBaMG77CELiw11dg==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2016-01-22T18:14:02.430Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```

I have tried a few examples online but all of them are invalid.
This is what I currently have.

```
protected function getHeaderXml()
    {
        $dateCreated = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');

        $nonce = base64_encode(sha1((mt_rand() . $dateCreated . self::PASSWORD)));

        return ' 
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://cdx.XXXXX.com/Api/0.99/" xmlns:deal="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXX.BaseApi" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <soapenv:Header>
                    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-29" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                        <wsse:Username>'.self::USERNAME.'</wsse:Username>
                        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">'.urlencode(self::PASSWORD).'</wsse:Password>
                        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'.$nonce.'</wsse:Nonce>
                        <wsu:Created>'.$dateCreated.'</wsu:Created>
                      </wsse:UsernameToken>
                    </wsse:Security>
                  </soapenv:Header>
                  <soapenv:Body>';
    }
```